# Delphi: Can I disable HINTS about inlining without disabling inlining itself?

Tags: delphi

I came here after having read this earlier question and its answers:

[Compiler Hint: "Inline function '...' has not been expanded..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649704/compiler-hint-inline-function-has-not-been-expanded)

I now understand what inlining and the compiler hint about it mean (thanks!), but I'd like to not see those hints, at least for now.

From [Embarcadero help](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/cm_inline_units_incomplete_xml.html) and similar,
I have found this comment saying:

> Note: You can disable these hints by turning off Inlining in Project->Options->Compiling

But my problem is, I don't want to disable inlining entirely! I want the compiler to inline where it can, but if it can't due to missing uses clauses, I don't want to be bothered by it.

Is this possible? I think you can't disable hints by type as you can warnings, and I can't think of other ways to do this, but does anyone have better ideas?

Oh, and it might be possible to put compiler directives to disable hints and then re-enable them in the code around every place where such hint comes, but after a Delphi update there may now be so many of them that I wouldn't want to be bothered by that, either (if I do that, than I could as well add the units to the `uses` clause).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints cannot be disabled individually. You either disable them all, or you enable them all.

In my view, the best way to deal with this is to add the function's declaring unit to the `uses` clause of the unit that uses the function.

Comment: That's what I expected (or my experience already - too bad). The main problem here is, that I'm moving from XE3 to Delphi 10 and at least for a while I'd like to keep the code usable (without hints & warnings) on both compilers, but if I add the unit to uses, it won't compile in XE3 (for certain cases of this warning). I can accomplish this by using conditional defines for VER300 in the uses clauses, but would have preferred being able to avoid even that. Well, can't get everything I guess. Thanks for the comments and edits also!